# Is this a valid method for Multiple Testing correction?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value, multiple-comparisons

A colleague described this multiple testing correction procedure to me some time ago.  I can't find a source, searching just pulls up tons of literature and websites explaining the well known methods.

1. Fix an ordering of the tests *before* testing for significance. $(H^{(1)}, H^{(2)}, ..., H^{(n)})$
2. Perform tests to obtain $(p^{(1)}, p^{(2)}, ...,  p^{(n)})$.
3. Multiply the p-value by the index of the test to get the adjusted p-value.  $p_{adj}^{(i)} = i \cdot p^{(i)}$.
4. Compare the adjusted p-value to $\alpha$.  If $p_{adj}^{(i)} < \alpha$, reject $H_{\varnothing}^{(i)}$.

The rationale is that it is like a rolling version of Bonferroni correction.  Since the order is fixed before significance is calculated, the later tests shouldn't affect the earlier tests.  The first test is as if we have only done one test, the second is as if we have only done two, and so on.  Also, if we later want to test additional results, we can pick back up and continuing correcting at $(n+1)$.

Is this valid?  Is there a source, proof, or name for it?